# Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-get(8))

Tags: ubuntu

I follow guide at https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/getting-started/quickstart.html

```
wget -qO - https://repository.hazelcast.com/api/gpg/key/public
sudo apt-key add - echo "deb https://repository.hazelcast.com/debian stable main"
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install hazelcast=5.1.1
```

[image]

Error

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-get(8)).
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328953/1178017

Comment: see also [Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead)

Answer (score -1):

apt-key now seems to be deprecated, I have created a script that will detect and get the missing keys, you can get it [here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2320252).

```
#!/bin/sh -e
tmp="$(mktemp)"
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | sed -En 's/.*NO_PUBKEY ([[:xdigit:]]+).*/\1/p' | sort -u > "${tmp}"
cat "${tmp}" | xargs sudo gpg --keyserver "hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443" --recv-keys  # to /usr/share/keyrings/*
cat "${tmp}" | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'sudo gpg --yes --output "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/$1.gpg" --export "$1"' sh  # to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
rm "${tmp}"
```